# keycloak-12.0.4 wildfly-21.0.2 Connection refused

Tags: ssl, wildfly, keycloak, keycloak-connect

myapp on wildfly-10 used keycloak-6 for authencation for 2 years without any issue. The SSL certificate expired and I have reinstall a new SSL and update to wildfly-21 and keycloak-12.
I am getting a Connection refused error.

Here is the list of different steps:

I installed Sectigo Essential Wildcard SSL for keycloak-12 as the following:

1. I issued a certificat from mydomain.net.csr
2. I received 3 files: _mydomain_net.crt, AAA_Certificate_Services.crt and USERTrust_RSA_Certification_Authority.crt
3. openssl pkcs12 -export -in _mydomain.crt -inkey mydomain.net.key -out mydomain.net.pl12 -name default -CAfile AAA_Certificate_Services.crt -caname root
4. keytool -importkeystore -destkeystore mydomain.net.jks -srckeystore mydomain.net.pl12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -alias default
5. cp mydomain.net.jks keycloak-12.0.4/standalone/configuration/

I configured keycloak standalone.xml as the following:

```
<security-realm name="UndertowRealm">
   <server-identities>
       <ssl>
            <keystore path="mydomain.net.jks" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir" keystore-password="mypass" />
       </ssl>
   </server-identities>
...
</security-realm>
   <https-listener name="https" socket-binding="https" security-realm="UndertowRealm" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="UndertowRealm"/>
                </host>
...
<spi name="truststore">
    <provider name="file" enabled="true">
        <properties>
            <property name="file" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/mydomain.net.jks"/>
            <property name="password" value="mypass"/>
            <property name="hostname-verification-policy" value="WILDCARD"/>
            <property name="disabled" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </provider>
</spi>
```

I added the certificated to the jvm

```
cp _mydomain_net.cert to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/
keytool -import -alias ca -file _mydomain.net.crt -keystore cacerts -storepass mypass
```

At this level I can access my keycloak installation via https without any issue.

I configured wildfly-21.0.2 as the following:

```
cp mydomain.net.jks standalone/configuration/mydomain.net.jks
```

I added a certificated to the jvm of my wildfly-21.0.2 server

```
cp _mydomain_net.cert to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/security/
keytool -import -alias ca -file _mydomain_net.crt -keystore cacerts -storepass mypass
```

my web.xml

```
   <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
         <url-pattern>/home/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
         <role-name>uma_authorization</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
   </security-constraint>

   <login-config>
      <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
   </login-config>

   <security-role>
      <role-name>uma_authorization</role-name>
   </security-role>
```

I can't connect myapp from wildfly-21 to keycloak-12, the error:

```
[org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeployment] (default task-1) Failed to load URLs from https://iam.mykeycloak.net/auth/realms/demo/.well-known/openid-configuration: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I am working on this issue for three days without any success and I have no idea on how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance for any idea/suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

https port was missing.
change https://iam.mykeycloak.net to https://iam.mykeycloak.net:8543